# Browser's 'Back' button goes to second to last page. Why?

Tags: javascript, browser, back-button

After adding this short js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //check to see if it's an external link and if so do the splashpage
    $('a').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        //get the redirect url
        var redirect_url = $this.attr('href');
        var string_url = String(redirect_url);
        if (string_url.indexOf("http") !== -1) {


            $('#external_link_modal').modal({
                overlayClose: true,
                overlayCss: {
                    backgroundColor: "#ebebeb"
                }
            });


            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.replace(string_url);
            }, 2500);
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

When someone clicks on a link (say on Page A) it pops up a warning then after some time, redirect the user to the new url (say Page B).

However, when someone clicks the browser's 'Back' button on page B, instead of taking user to Page A like it's supposed to, it actually takes him to the page viewed **before** Page A.

It's really weird.
Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: No JS expert here but is this an issue with index versus non-index values being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.replace(string_url)` replaces the current history entry with `string_url`. You should set `window.location.href` instead:

```
window.location.href = string_url;
```

Comment: Thank you. That works and appreciate the explanation of the browser's 'Back' button behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but try replacing:

`window.location.replace(string_url)`

with:

`window.location.href=string_url`

Let me know if that solves the problem or if it exhibits the same behavior.